# Map key combo as WinKey

Tags: windows, keyboard, macros

I just bought a ThinkPad style desktop keyboard that has no Windows key.  Is it possible to configure a specific key combo to behave like the Windows key?

Answer (score 0):

Found a program that gets close enough: [KeyTweak](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/keytweak/) can map just about any key as any key, including the WinKey.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do this with several third-party applications:

[SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/) lets you remap keys one-to-one, so you can use this if you want a single key (e.g., Caps Lock) to work as a Windows Key.

[AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) lets you write more advanced scripts and would allow you to use combinations (e.g., Ctrl+Shift+W) to send a Windows Key.